# How do I use the popstate function with javascript + ajax, not jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, pushstate, popstate

Sorry for newbie question here, I am missing something, probably easy, but vital about javascript I guess..

I have an ajax-website, with four html pages, index.php, food_and_health.php, enlightenment.php, and about_us.php.
I have ajax functions in the three, not index.

And I do understand I need to add the popstate function, for using back and forward, and I am looking into a tutorial at this moment, as u see, I only have console log.

I get the console message, 'foo is not defined', and I tried making it a global variable, with no luck, as I don't quite know if that is the problem either.

I have no anchor, or anything in my html, that has the id of 'foo', but I tried changing from foo, to 'text', and to 'cssmenu', in my js.file, and tried adding id='foo' to one of my anchor tags, in my html, but still same message.

So I guess, that it is a local variable, inside my ajax function.
Actually, the page works, except back and forward, and if I try to navigate directly to an ajax-page/ state.
I know this is, because I need to set some data in my popstate function, I am thinking that something like this.url will work there also, like in my pushstate-function.(conjunction between push-state and popstate is what I am missing.)

But how do I add the popstate function? Do I need to specify for each page, or can I somehow say, take this.url, as it is done in the pushstate function, and have that state used, as it is saved in pushstate?

I guess I need to link the popstate, in the ajaxfuntion also, somehow..

2nd question, not that important thou.
Why do my console log display some jQuery? Is that because of the 'google-apis', link I have for my font(tangerine)? As I do not use any jQuery, I was surpriced that my index-page is using jQuery, but I think that is the issue.
In my console, I have jquery.1.8.2.min.js, and collectorjQuery.js
Are these from 'googleapis'? :)

I will add a jsfiddle also, this shows my food_and_health.php page, and my css and js. (Ignore the css mostly, just added for looking 'ok') :

http://jsfiddle.net/y0o39897/4/

And the cssmenu will not open in the fiddle, but opens in chrome and firefox at least.

Here is my js, that I am struggling a bit with!

```
function Food(url) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            history.pushState({}, 'foo', url);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

foo.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Food(this.href);
    return false;
}, true);

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

    console.log(e);

});
```

I have read a lot of pages about this, and as I can understand it;
The pushstate takes any state, in my case this.url, the url/anchor that is clicked, and saves that state.
The popstate will then, use that state, for navigating back and forward, between the ajax pages in that html page.
If I want to navigate back from say, page2/ajaxfile.php, to page1/someotherAjaxpage.php, I would need replacestate. Is this correct?

Sorry for lengthy question, and 2 questions in one, but as I am newbie, and want to be as clear as possible about this, and understand it fully, and that is why I try not to use jQuery.

I struggle to find tutorial with ajax-popstate-and javascript(not jQuery).
Thanks for any help on this :)

Comment: Where did you define the variable foo? I am not seeing it in your code.

Comment: Any improvements on my js would be appreciated, I know it is very newbie coded, and that I am repating my activemenu functions.
I also would like to have these 3 functions shortened down, and I will change my onclicks to click-event, when I can get this popstate working :)

Comment: @epascarello
That would be the issue yes, where do I define it? Or, what is it? I am not understanding this fully..

Comment: It would be a reference to an element that you want to add a click event too.

Comment: You define it, and set it to a reference to the element that you want to respond to a click on. (Side note: You almost certainly want `false`, not `true`, as the third argument to `addEventListener`.)

Comment: I tried to define it like this: 
    window['foo'] = foo;

Comment: No, it is supposed to be like `var foo = document.getElementById("someElementsId");`

Comment: Ahh, I see, yes that seemed more logic :)

Comment: I suggest stepping away from your current task and instead working through some more tutorials on basic web programming. It's important to have a grasp of the fundamentals before you try to do more advanced things like history management.

Comment: Hm, would that elemnts id, be my entrire cssmenu? Or would I have to add an id for all my anchor tags? Or maybe my text, wich is the only part I am changing with ajax? :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Will do that, I have thought about the same thing:)
Would you recommend something besides buckysroom tutorial?

And thanks for quick responses both :)

Comment: Ah, when I changed from true, to false as you said, the page stopped loading on forever, so I see the need of that. Will read more about addeventlistener, and the javascript basic structure.

But Could I ask, is the way I am looking at the popstate, push state, replace state correct? What I asked in the last part of my question? :)

Comment: @epascarello
Should I declare the variable 'foo' as an array, or maybe object in this situation?
Example mypage1=page1, or just use array, to give it numbers that the THIS command can easely understand/relate to.., [mypage1,mypage2]; etc :)
I am getting more understanding know, so should get the hang of it myself.
But, ehm the push and popstate has events, and these, I could assign in an object i suppose? So that every menu-item, has a state, that js can find, something like: {myAjaxpage1 = page1};, where page 1 is the state?

Reading more here, but pointers and help are always useful :)